# Submit Aws Amplify React App to Google Search Console for Indexing

Tags: dns, seo

When submitting my website to google for indexing, I am given a TXT with the instruction "Copy the TXT record below into the DNS configuration for example.com" where example.come is the name of my url. My website is a react app currently hosted on aws amplify, and the domain is managed by aws.

Because the domain is managed by aws, I am unable to edit the dns on godaddy because I changed the namespace (to let aws manage the domain) when using the domain name on aws amplify [image]

Now my question is, how do I use the TXT record given to me by google search console when I can no longer edit my dns records in godaddy? Will appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit and append the TXT record in Route 53, the AWS DNS service. In the console, search for the service and edit your domain: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route-53-configure-long-spf-txt-records/

Comment: Worked for me. Created a TXT record in route 53 and got the domain verified. Thank you.